# handling link opening event in HtmlView

Tags: nativescript

I have a html code that has a link inside it. code below is my template:

```
<HtmlView [html]="htmlString" ></HtmlView>
```

this is my component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./creating-htmlview.component.html"
})

export class CreatingHtmlViewExampleComponent {
    public htmlString: string;

    constructor() {
        this.htmlString = '<a href="http://google.com/">google</a>';
    }
}
```

how to handle `a` element inside of HtmlView when it run ? there is a way to detect when user run the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported yet, there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3671). You may write a plugin that implements native apis like ClickableSpan or Linkify.